# Restore database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I have some sql server's backup file(format .bck). In my case, I do not know log file name.
So I can't use `with move` in restore command.
Is there anyway to restore database without move? If yes, please guide me.

I want to use like below one.

```
restore database testdb from disk = 'folderpath\aatest.bak'
```

Answer (score 3):

You sure can know the log file name and use `WITH MOVE`. Use [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to retrieve the list of database files (including log) from the backup first.

Comment: One of my files has data,log file's name are same, only file extension are different. for example `data file = 'C:\user\test\db.ADF'`        `log file = 'C:\user\test\db.ALF'`

Comment: So I can't use move, that why I said do not want `with move` part.

Comment: rename to change extension is a `MOVE`

Comment: I have tried like following, but noting will happened always throws `is not part of database` error. 
`1)RESTORE DATABASE test from disk='test.bak' WITH MOVE 'ADF' TO 'F:\test.adf', move 'ALF' To 'F:\test.alf';`
`2)RESTORE DATABASE test from disk='test.bak' WITH MOVE 'test.ADF' TO 'F:\test.adf', move 'test.ALF' To 'F:\test.alf';`